# In Winforms, whenever I edit the form I lose other changes I've made to Designer.cs, but I can't figure out how to add a "Resize Event" normally

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to get a resize event working, and I tried just adding "this.Reszie += whatever" and that worked fine, but whenever I make other changes to the Form through the editor, it completely erases that line (as well as anything else in the Form1.Designer.cs class). My questions is, how can I edit this as intentioned, like how double clicking on a button or text box will automatically do this all? Thanks

Comment: Don't edit the .Designer.cs -- that file is auto-generated. Edit the corresponding file name which doesn't have ".Designer" in it

Comment: Oh! Thanks Olivier! That was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can select event handlers in the properties window. You must click on the flash symbol, to switch form properties to events view.

Also, before you do manual changes to ".designer.cs", close the form designer (because saving the form overwrites the ".designer.cs" file).

Usually, you should avoid doing changes in the ".designer.cs" file, but there are rare occasions where this is helpful. E.g., you have used a `TextBox` and want to replace it by a custom textbox or third-party textbox. Then changing the type manually will allow you to do it without removing  and re-adding these controls.

Comment: Right, this was perfectly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Just adding: when you want to initialize components with a default dynamic value (like DateTime.Today on a DateTimerPicker)

Comment: @IgorHenriques Do that from within the non-Designer file. Don't edit the Designer file to do that